# Tests fails if in method with yandex.allure annotaion @Step was thrown exception

Tags: java, selenium, appium, allure

I try to use yandex.allure with testng. My test call next method:

```
@Override
@Step("Is element {0} present")
public boolean isElementPresent(AndroidElement element) {
    try {
        element.isDisplayed(); //<== element not present on screen
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        return false; // <== method return false value
    }
}
```

Method returns false, but test fails.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by this strategy: Locator map: 
- native content: "By.xpath: //*[@resource-id='ru.tfw_mob.devtest:id/menu_overflow']" 
- html content: "by id or name "mainMenuBtn""
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'vitekes', ip: '192.168.200.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:110)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.interceptors.InterceptorOfASingleElement.intercept(InterceptorOfASingleElement.java:57)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c898a80.toString(<generated>)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.subformat(MessageFormat.java:1280)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:865)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:841)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.aspects.AllureAspectUtils.getTitle(AllureAspectUtils.java:65)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.aspects.AllureStepsAspects.createTitle(AllureStepsAspects.java:70)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.aspects.AllureStepsAspects.stepStart(AllureStepsAspects.java:42)
    at tfw.qa.mobile.core.drivers.commands.DriverCommandsImpl.isElementPresent(DriverCommandsImpl.java:144)
    at tfw.qa.mobile.pages.elements.MainPageElements.isMainMenuOpenerVisible(MainPageElements.java:149)
    at tfw.qa.mobile.pages.android.MainPage.isMainMenuOpenBtnVisible(MainPage.java:29)
    at tfw.qa.mobile.pages.android.LoginPage.logout(LoginPage.java:42)
    at tfw.qa.mobile.demo.BaseTest.tearDownAction(BaseTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)
```

Without @Step test works fine.
Error is also repeated with other annotations eg @Attachment and others.
Can anybody explain why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `@Step` instantinate `AndroidElement` and trigger findElement method which causes `NoSuchElementException`. Add helper method with `@Step` annotation and `String` parameter and call it from your `isElementPresent()`. Just pass `AndroidElement.toString()` into.